# Multiple of document.getElementById("elementId").innerHTML = () causing second one to return as null

Tags: javascript

First, let me explain what I'm trying to do: I want to make a script for a video game that counts how much money is in the game, and create an element to display it. The tracking the money part was easy, but apparently making elements is like the most confusing thing i've tried to do yet.

Lightshot screenshot of chrome console: https://prnt.sc/shszc2
The blue-highlighted line in the screenshot gave an error after being executed twice. I boxed the error message in red.

I'll take some code out of the script I have, mainly aiming for code that is important for the issue i want help with, leaving out code that I understand.

Also note that I am extremely new to generating graphics in Javascript, so if my ways of making elements are horrendous, then it's because I just kept trying random crap until something seemed to work and stuck with whatever that was.

```
// The elements that I created. Again i know next to nothing about elements, so the only thing that I 
// know will work is this catastrophe. 
var initialDiv = document.getElementById('onecup');

mainText = initialDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('mainText'));
mainText.style.position = 'absolute';
mainText.style.left="50%";
mainText.style.top="64px"
mainText.style.width = "290px";
mainText.style.height = "160px";
mainText.style.color = "white";
mainText.style.zindex = 1;
mainText.style.fontSize = "18px"

trackerBack = mainText.appendChild(document.createElement('trackerBack'));
trackerBack.style.position = 'absolute';
trackerBack.style.left="-200px"
trackerBack.style.top="0px"
trackerBack.style.width = "400px";
trackerBack.style.height = "160px";
trackerBack.style.backgroundColor = "black";
trackerBack.style.opacity = ".20"
trackerBack.style.zindex=1;

diffTotal = trackerBack.appendChild(document.createElement('diffTotal'));
diffTotal.id = "diffTotal"
diffTotal.style.position = 'absolute';
diffTotal.style.top="20%"
diffTotal.style.left="40%";
diffTotal.style.color = "rgba(255,255,255,255)";
diffTotal.style.opacity = "1"
diffTotal.style.zindex = 2;
diffTotal.style.fontSize = "30px"

diffFielded = diffTotal.appendChild(document.createElement('diffFielded'));
diffFielded.id = "diffFielded"
diffFielded.style.position = 'absolute';
diffFielded.style.top="-15px"
diffFielded.style.left="0px";
diffFielded.style.color = "rgba(255,255,255,255)";
diffFielded.style.opacity = "1"
diffFielded.style.zindex = 2;
diffFielded.style.fontSize = "20px"

// This function is used by a latter function to set the values of the text elements. I initially didn't 
// have this but thought adding it would help, but nothing changed.
// By the way, "toBna2" stands for to "big number abbreviation". It doesn't do anything major, besides
// shrink down numbers. Tried removing it, problem still persists.
conductValues = function(targetName, targetAssignment) {
    document.getElementById(targetName).innerHTML = toBna2(targetAssignment)
}

// This looping function controls the values that the elements display. However, I removed the code that 
// tells the function what values to make the elements, so if you want to test it, I guess just define 
// the 4 values as anything or make your own.
findValueDiff = setInterval(function() {

// If i make one of these lines a comment, it works, regardless of which one it is. But if i let both of 
// them run, the second document.getElementById("elementId") returns as null. Always the second one.
   conductValues("diffTotal", (aValP + aValU - bValP - bValU))
   conductValues("diffFielded", (aValU - bValU))
}
```

I even tried doing this:

```
conductValues = function(targetName, targetAssignment) {
  if (document.getElementById(targetName) != "undefined") {
    document.getElementById(targetName).innerHTML = toBna2(targetAssignment)
  }
}
```

But all that does is make the function fail on the first attempt, because **always** the second `document.getElementById("elementId")` returns as null.

I'm not entirely sure if I included enough information, but I don't know what else to add so hopefully I did. But if you need more information, just ask and i'll try to edit this post as swiftly as possible.

Thanks to all responders, and I hope you stay healthy as you have fun coding.

Edit 1: Thought i would get something different if I set the entity's variables one at a time like this:

```
conductValues = function(targetName, targetAssignment) {
    document.getElementById(targetName).innerHTML = toBna2(targetAssignment)
}

loopMode=0

findValueDiff = setInterval(function() {
    if (loopMode == 0) {
      conductValues("diffTotal", (aValP + aValU - bValP - bValU))
      loopMode = 1
    } else {
      conductValues("diffFielded", (aValU - bValU))
      loopMode = 0 
    }
  }, 1000
);
```

But the problem still hasn't changed. Second time it tries to update, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I got it:

```
diffTotal = trackerBack.appendChild(document.createElement('diffTotal'));
diffFielded = diffTotal.appendChild(document.createElement('diffFielded'));

conductValues("diffTotal", (aValP + aValU - bValP - bValU))
conductValues("diffFielded", (aValU - bValU))

conductValues = function(targetName, targetAssignment) {
    document.getElementById(targetName).innerHTML = toBna2(targetAssignment)
}
```

Those are the lines, which cause the error.
`diffFielded` is a child of `diffTotal`. In the first `conductValues` call, you replace the innerHTML of `diffTotal`. When you are doing this, you are removing `diffFielded`, because it's replaces by the new value and then it cannot by found anymore because it does not exist anymore.

I assume `diffFielded` should actually be another child of `trackerBack`, so you should do:

```
diffFielded = trackerBack.appendChild(document.createElement('diffFielded'));
```

Tip:
Move the style stuff into a css file.